# How to run a ServiceNow Application Server Script in the background?

Tags: background, servicenow

I want to periodically perform some maintenance in the background. Googling for how to do this gives me ['Scripts-Background module'](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/london-application-development/page/script/server-scripting/concept/c_ScriptsBackground.html). This is for one off, non production background scripts.

The current solution I'm thinking is when requests come in, I check if there's an entry in my new background task table. If not, insert. Then I add an async business rule to perform the work then delete the row from the table.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a [Scheduled Script Execution](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/madrid-platform-administration/page/administer/reference-pages/task/t_ScheduleAScriptExecution.html)

Basically, if you have server-side javascript, and you want to run it on some fixed interval (hourly, daily, weekly, etc.), that's your answer.

Although, it sort of sounds like your maintenance script is going to be triggered by other action (*"...when requests come in..."*), but I'm not totally clear on the problem you're trying to solve. If there's more detail to that that you can share, there may be other options for you.

Comment: Is this something that can be included as part of a ServiceNow application?

Comment: We haven't decided if it needs to be fixed interval, or triggered by a script scripted api. We're leaning towards trigged by a scripted rest api.